# Why do I have to copy an FTP stream to another variable to return it to the calling method?

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, getresponsestream

I am building some code to download images via `FtpWebRequest`.  When I collect the response to the `DownloadFile` stream the only way that I've been able to return the image in memory to the calling function is to use `MyResponseStream.CopyTo(MyMemoryStream)` and then `Return MyMemoryStream`.  This works, but I don't get why I need to create two copies of an image in memory (which could potentially be very large).  When I try to return `MyResponseStream` directly the code just hangs out somewhere in space and I have to stop the debugger.

Why can't I just do this?: `Return MyResponseStream` in the code below?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Function GetJpgImage(ByVal ImageID As Integer)
    'returns image file from server in a memoryStream
    'code from: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/77912-ftp-download-delete/

    'build requested file string
    Dim MyRequestedFile As String
    MyRequestedFile = ImageID.ToString & ".jpg"

    'create FTP request
    Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://mysite.com/www/downloads/" & MyRequestedFile), FtpWebRequest)
    ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("mySpecialUser", "superSecretPwd")
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = True 
    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = False 'No Zombies

    'check if file exists (sigh... do it later)

    'select download method
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

    'setup for response
    Dim MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream
    Dim FTPResponse As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(ftpRequest.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)

    'send request and return memoryStream
    Using MyResponseStream As IO.Stream = FTPResponse.GetResponseStream
        'copy to memory stream so we can close the FTP connection
        MyResponseStream.CopyTo(MyMemoryStream)  '<== Why God? Why?
        'close FTP stream
        MyResponseStream.Close()
        'gimme my data!
        Return MyMemoryStream
    End Using
End Function
```

It doesn't have anything to do with `MyResponseStream` being in a `Using` statement (I tried it).  VS 2012, Win8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you have the function declared like:

```
Public Function GetJpgImage(ByVal ImageID As Integer) as MemoryStream
```

if you are returning:

```
 Return MyMemoryStream
```

**EDIT:** Try changing the return statement out of the using, Just for testing.
It doesn't really matter if you include your return inside the using statement
but just to be sure. Because the behaviour you are experiencing is not normal as well

```
 Using MyResponseStream As IO.Stream = FTPResponse.GetResponseStream
    'copy to memory stream so we can close the FTP connection
    MyResponseStream.CopyTo(MyMemoryStream)  '<== Why God? Why?
    'close FTP stream
    MyResponseStream.Close()
    'gimme my data!

End Using

Return MyMemoryStream
```

**EDIT2:**. If you dont want to use the Copy To, try to read the stream into the memoryStream using the traditional way:

```
MemoryStream memStream;
using (Stream response = request.GetResponseStream()) {
    memStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int byteCount;
    do {
        byteCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
    } while (byteCount > 0);
}
```

Comment: I actually did have it declared that way originally and it didn't seem to make a difference for this question.  In the end I'll add that back in again.  Just to be sure, I tested using `as MemoryStream` as well as `as IO.Stream` in the function declare.  Still hangs when I try to return `MyResponseStream`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Just trying to help because it is really weird

Comment: Appreciate the ideas, Let me add some clarity here.  The code in the question as posted works, but I'm trying to figure out why in the world I have to use the `CopyTo()` method in order to return the stream.  I tried using a DIM statement instead of the using structure and still had the same result, so I don't think the `Using` method is the issue.  Although I didn't directly try that idea I have effectively tested that variant and it works the same as leaving it inside.  And on the same idea, I can't return `MyResponseStream` outside of the using block because it has been disposed by then.

Comment: You are returning MyMemoryStream no Response. Who it's declared previous to the using statement

Comment: MyMemoryStream works, it returns what I need.  But I don't like having to use the `CopyTo()` method.  I'm trying to optimize here because I don't want to have two copies of the same image in memory.  I'd rather return `MyResponseStream` directly but that doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: I update my question. Just read the stream into the memorystream and Do not use the CopyTo

Comment: I'm trying to understand the difference between copying 1024 bytes at a time and copying the whole thing at the same time.  Maybe my understanding of the response stream is incorrect.  I'm assuming that the response stream is held in memory somewhere and that I can just pass a reference to that memory location without moving/copying it.  The calling function then moves the stream out of memory however it wants to (by saving a file in this case).  Is the response stream stored in a way that I HAVE to move it to use it elsewhere?  I can't reference the original stream memory location?

Comment: I guess the difference is that there is only a buffer of 1024 bytes instead of a full copy of both images...  Answering my own original question in the last comment.  Still curious about the memory location of the original response stream.